# Use a custom Layout in a LazyColumn item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I would like to use a custom layout to display a list a of musics records inside a LazyColumn item. This custom layout have to display the list on 2 columns like this :

```
[LazyColumn] {
    [item1] {
      [1] [2]
      [3] [4]
      [5] [6]
      [7] ...
    }
    [item2] {
      [1] [2]
      [3] [4]
    }
    [item3] {
      [1] [2]
      [3] [4]
      [5] [6]
      ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Here is my implementation of the layout:

```
@Composable
fun TwoColumnsLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable ()-> Unit
){
    Layout(//the basic building block for custom layout
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ){measurables, constraints->
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight){

            val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
                // Measure each children
                measurable.measure(constraints)
            }

            // Set the size of the layout as big as it can
            layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
                // Track the y co-ord we have placed children up to
                var xPosition = 0
                var yPosition = 0
                var index = 0

                // Place children in the parent layout
                placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                    // Position item on the screen
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = xPosition, y = yPosition)

                    if(index % 2 == 0){
                        xPosition += placeable.width
                    }else{
                        xPosition -= placeable.width
                        yPosition += placeable.height
                    }
                    index ++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the composable where I want to use the layout:

```
@Composable
fun ExpandableCard(dataList: Map<String, List<Song>>) {

    val expandedStates = remember {
        mutableStateMapOf(
            *dataList.keys.map { it to false }.toTypedArray()
        )
    }

    LazyColumn(
        Modifier.padding(horizontal = 8.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
    ) {

        for ((category, songList) in dataList) {

            item {
                expandedStates[category]?.let { boolState ->
                    CategoryHeader(
                        category,
                        boolState,
                        animateFloatAsState(if (expandedStates[category] == true) 180f else 0f).value
                    ) { bool -> expandedStates[category] = !bool }
                }
            }

            if (expandedStates[category] == true) {
                item {
                    TwoColumnsLayout {
                        { for (song in songList) {SongItem(song)} }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The layout seems to not render correctly and I do not even see my SongItems in the Lazy column. How can I display the 2 columns properly in the lazyColumn ?

[EDIT]

Here is he answer of my post:

```
@Composable
fun TwoColumnsLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
){
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = content
    ){measurables, constraints ->

            val placeables = measurables.map { measurable ->
                measurable.measure(constraints.copy(maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth / 2))
            }

            var rowsHeight = listOf<Int>()
            for(i in placeables.indices) {
                if(i % 2 != 0 ){
                    rowsHeight += maxOf(placeables[i-1].height, placeables[i].height)
                }else if (i == placeables.size-1){
                    rowsHeight += placeables[i].height
                }
            }
            layout(constraints.maxWidth, rowsHeight.sum()) {

                // Track the y co-ord we have placed children up to
                var xPosition = 0
                var yPosition = 0
                var index = 0
                // track height of both elements of the row
                var firstPlaceableHeight = 0

                // Place children in the parent layout
                placeables.forEach { placeable ->

                    // Position item on the screen
                    placeable.placeRelative(x = xPosition, y = yPosition)

                    if(index % 2 == 0){
                        firstPlaceableHeight = placeable.height
                        xPosition += placeable.width
                    }else{
                        xPosition = 0
                        yPosition += maxOf(firstPlaceableHeight, placeable.height)
                    }
                    index ++
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see 4 problems in your code:

1. You are calling `layout()` twice inside the `measure` lambda. You can call it just once, remove the first call, create the placeables first and then call `layout()`.
2. You want to have two columns, but you measure each measurable with the constraints of parent. You need to do something like `measurable.measure(constraints.copy(maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth / 2))` if you want each cell to occupy at most half of the space, so you can have two columns.
3. You are calling `layout` with `height = constraints.maxHeight`, but you will have to provide actual height of your content, because lazy column and each of its child is measured with infinite max height.
4. You only increment `yPosition` with the height of the second item in the row, this will only work if your items are of same height. It might be better to add the height of the highest item in each row.

Comment: To find the height of my TwoColumnsLayout I guess I have to measure the height of each of my placeables individually in a for loop or something. How can I get the height of a placeble ?

Comment: Yeah, something like that.. height of placeable is simply `placeable.height`, you are already using that, you will just have to do that already before `layout` call. Then, depending on the layout logic, you'd probably take all placeables chunked by column count, get max height of each chunk (row) and sum that.

Comment: Thank you for your help! All working properly now. I'll edit my post to show the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use LazyVerticalGrid

```
val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
LazyVerticalGrid(
    columns = GridCells.Adaptive(minSize = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp / 2)
) {
    items(items = list) { item ->
        // your each item 
        // if you want to handle of the child
        // you can try with seal class either object to switch the view
        // base on item type .....
    }
}
```

or with fixed cells

```
columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
```